# Finding a hyperbola's equation based off given asymptotes

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, hyperbolic-functions

I need help finding the equation of a hyperbola that opens vertically with asymptotes $y=2x+11$ and $y=-2x-1$. I also need help finding the equation of a different hyperbola that also opens upwards with the same asymptotes.

I mostly need help with the second one, but they relate, so it'd be great if you guys could give me hints on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation of the two asymptotes:
$$
(2x+11-y)(-2x-1-y)=0
$$
Equations of hyperbolas with these asymptotes:
$$
(2x+11-y)(-2x-1-y)=c
$$
for nonzero constant $c$.  For one sign of $c$ it "opens vertically" and for the other sign it doesn't.

Comment: So, does it open vertically for any c>0?

Comment: Why not try it and see?